# Change the behaviour of "imeOptions" (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textview, imeoptions

This is my problem right now, guys.

I have the next TextView and EditText

#### activity_profile.xml

```
<TextView
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/done"
            android:id="@+id/done_profile_btn"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
<EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/input_profile_swift"
            android:hint="@string/swift"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
```

And I would like to change the action that press the 'Done' button on the keyboard does for the EditText in order to do the same as the TextView, which does the next:

#### ProfileActivity.java

```
done_btn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.done_profile_btn);
swift = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_profile_swift);
done_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                //saveChanges();
                //finish();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your changes have been saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
...
```

So... I want that both (press 'Done' on my keyboard and press the TextView) do the same.

Any idea of how to do that? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one also (sets a special listener to be called when an action is performed on the EditText), **it works both for DONE and RETURN:**

```
swift.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
              //saveChanges();
              //finish();
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your changes have been saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }    
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Hope it will help !

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
EditText swift = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_profile_swift);
swift.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your changes have been saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
});
```

You have to implements OnEditorActionListener interface and set it to your EditText. using **setOnEditorActionListener(OnEditorActionListener implimentation.)**

Answer (score 0):

Use TextView.OnEditorActionListener.

```
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(final TextView v, final int actionId, final KeyEvent event) {
    KeyboardHelper.hideSoftKeyboard(getActivity());
    doSomeWoorrkThatYouNeed();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add this `android:clickable="true"` to your xml for the `TextView`.
Also you could set an EditorActionListener using `setOnEditorActionListener` on your `EditText` in similar way that you did with `setOnClickListener` for your `TextView`.